# Apache / Reverse Proxy / IP

Tags: apache, ip, reverse-proxy

When sending a request to the main server through the reverse proxy, the sender's IP address is changed to the IP address of the reverse proxy server. Can someone tell me how to do it so that the sender's IP address does not change?

In file *.conf ProxyPreserveHost On change off